# orWhere vs Where Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have the following code:

```
$results = \DB::table('pack')
            ->Join('users as u1', 'u1.id', '=', 'pack.userid')
            ->Join('skills as s1', 's1.packid', '=', 'pack.packid')
            ->where('u_status', '=', "0")
            ->where('pack.amount', '<', 100)
            ->where('pack.amount', '>', 10)                 
            ->where('pack_status', '=', "2")
            ->where('pack.title', 'LIKE', "%$text%")
            ->orWhere('pack.description', 'LIKE', "%$text%")
            ->orWhere('pack.skills', 'LIKE', "%$text%")
            ->orWhere('s1.name', 'LIKE', "%$text%")
            ->orderBy('packid', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('featured', 'desc')
            ->groupBy('packid')
            ->take(40)
            ->get();
return $results;
```

Everything is working except `->where('amount', '<', 100)` and `->where('amount', '>', 10)`.

It does not exclude either of those, and shows amounts above and below the numbers I set. If I remove the `orWhere()` it works fine.

Am I using `orWhere()` and `where()` correctly?

Comment: i think you have something wrong this will translate to 

 u_status = 0 AND pack.amount < 100 pack.title LIKE %$text% OR WHERE pack.description LIKE %$text%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you've combined ORs and ANDs without grouping them properly. Think about the following conditions:

```
$bool1 = false && false || true; // =true
$bool2 = false && (false || true); // =false
```

So, to get this to work properly, you need to group your conditions properly. You can group conditions by passing a closure to the `where()` or `orWhere()` methods. I'm guessing you want to group the `$text` conditions together, so your code would look like:

```
$results = \DB::table('pack')
    ->join('users as u1', 'u1.id', '=', 'pack.userid')
    ->join('skills as s1', 's1.packid', '=', 'pack.packid')
    ->where('u_status', '=', "0")
    ->where('pack.amount', '<', 100)
    ->where('pack.amount', '>', 10)                 
    ->where('pack_status', '=', "2")
    ->where(function($query) use ($text) {
        $query->where('pack.title', 'LIKE', "%$text%")
            ->orWhere('pack.description', 'LIKE', "%$text%")
            ->orWhere('pack.skills', 'LIKE', "%$text%")
            ->orWhere('s1.name', 'LIKE', "%$text%");
    })
    ->orderBy('packid', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('featured', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('packid')
    ->take(40)
    ->get();

return $results;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database row matches any of the `orWhere` it will show the row. In your code you have

```
->orWhere('pack.description', 'LIKE', "%$text%")
->orWhere('pack.skills', 'LIKE', "%$text%")
->orWhere('s1.name', 'LIKE', "%$text%")
```

If you row matches any of them it will ignore other `where` or `orWhere`

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to make it so that it does not ignore the `where` even if the `orWhere` has a result?